# How to batch sell equipments?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Basically I am clearing out my storage box by selling equipment that I don't use.

However I do have a lot of equipment to sell (a few pages worth), and from the image below, I didn't see any shortcut keys to mass-select equipment to sell them.

[image: Image of Sell-Equipment interface]

Is there any simple way to batch sell a number of equipment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only sell each equipment individually. This doesn't change with Iceborne.

On the PS4 at least, it is like 3 button presses to sell each equipment. If you know which parts you want to sell, you can be fairly fast in selling those. Yet, if you are not sure which items you want to sell, be careful as there is no buy-back option (at least none that I know of).

Comment: A shame that you can batch sell items/consumables, but not equipment. Hopefully they add it in the future.

Comment: Batch sell is only for 1 slot always. Though the "trade-in" items are not counted into it. Also the only weapons you would really want to sell in batches are the useless Kulve Taroth weapons. Every other weapon you crafted and invested time into it. Those might be very strong when upgraded